# Как грамотно реализовать код чистыми функциями?

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести узел с макс/мин значением.

Как это сделать чистыми функциями?
Как сделать рекурсивную функцию, чтобы она возвращала узел?

```js
var obj={value:14,children:[{value:33,children:[{value:9,children:[{value:35},{value:69},{value:6}]},{value:47,children:[{value:4}]},{value:52,children:[{value:74},{value:55}]}]},{value:88,children:[{value:71,children:[{value:35}]},{value:6,children:[{value:74}]},{value:26,children:[{value:80},{value:42}]}]}]};

const minValue = obj =>
  Math.min(obj.value, ...(obj.children || []).map(minValue));
const maxValue = obj =>
  Math.max(obj.value, ...(obj.children || []).map(maxValue));

const showNode = obj => console.log(obj);
const isRight = (obj, someValue) => obj.value === someValue;

const req = objItem => {
  (objItem.children || []).map(req);
  if (isRight(objItem, minValue(obj))) {
    showNode(objItem);
  }
  if (isRight(objItem, maxValue(obj))) {
    showNode(objItem);
  }
};

req(obj);

//console.log(maxNode(obj));
//console.log(minNode(obj));
```

Comment: А разве эти функции не чистые насколько позволяет язык? Они ведь не меняют внешнее состояние, и зависят только от своих входных данных. Или тут смысл "решение должно быть чистой функцией"?

Comment: @yar85 вроде как в условии стоит чтобы вывод был в таком формате //console.log(maxNode(obj));
//console.log(minNode(obj)) Но как функцию сделать чтобы она возвратила максимальный/минимальный узел, передавая в неё только объект или такое решения как у меня нормально?

Comment: Утверждать не возьмусь, но вроде нормально... задача же выполняется, верно? Только вывод наверное стоит ограничить изменением кода `showNode` - чтобы веточки от узлов в `children` не вываливать в консоль целиком (например, показывать только `typeof` первого уровня вложенности, чтобы было понятно лист/нелист).

Answer (score 0):

Для вывод узла - не обязательно сначала искать значение, а потом по значению опять искать узел. Достаточно сразу возвращать узел целиком, а не одно его поле.

Например:

```js
var obj={value:14,children:[{value:33,children:[{value:9,children:[{value:35},{value:69},{value:6}]},{value:47,children:[{value:4}]},{value:52,children:[{value:74},{value:55}]}]},{value:88,children:[{value:71,children:[{value:35}]},{value:6,children:[{value:74}]},{value:26,children:[{value:80},{value:42}]}]}]};

const minNode = obj =>{
  const minChild = (obj.children||[]).map(minNode).reduce((a,b)=>a.value<b.value?a:b,{value:Infinity});
  return obj.value < minChild.value ? obj : minChild;  
};
const maxNode = obj =>{
  const maxChild = (obj.children||[]).map(maxNode).reduce((a,b)=>a.value>b.value?a:b,{value:-Infinity});
  return obj.value > maxChild.value ? obj : maxChild;  
}


console.log(maxNode(obj));
console.log(minNode(obj));
```